# How to automatically resize the vagrant disk image size for linux guests?

Tags: vagrant

There are numerous steps online for manually increasing the vagrant disk size, for example: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317338/how-can-i-increase-disk-size-on-a-vagrant-vm)

It would be great if the resize could be done automatically in the `Vagrantfile`, something like this:

```
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    if first_up      # only run on the first 'up' command
      disk_uuid = ?  # how to get the disk_uuid?
      vb.customize ["modifyhd", disk_uuid, "--resize", "15360"]
      config.vm.provision "shell", path: "resize2fs -p -F /dev/sda"
    end
  end
```

**Question**: How can I find out the disk uuid in a cross platform way?

**Question**: Is this all that is required to resize the guest's disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the following options to be useful:

**1) Add another disk to the Vagrant box.**

See my answer to a similar question on AskUbuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/404500).

**2) Use Opscode Vagrant boxes which tend to have 40Gb disks**

See the [opscode page](https://github.com/opscode/bento) for more information.

**3) Use [packer](http://www.packer.io/) to create your own box.**

After reading the packer tutorials, you can start by copying the packer definitions from somewhere else (e.g. [opscode](https://github.com/opscode/bento)) and tweak the disk size.

---

Some more information:

An issue was raised on [Vagrant's issue tracker](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2339) about extending vagrant disks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [vagrant-disksize](https://github.com/sprotheroe/vagrant-disksize) plugin.

You can install it by executing:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-disksize`

Then you can include it in the Vagrantfile like this:

```rb
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'
  config.disksize.size = '50GB'
end
```

Its limited at the moment only to the first disk.